# vite-plugin-pages got error Cannot find module '~pages' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

I am creating my vue project with typescript via `vite`, and I use [vite-plugin-pages](https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages) for my router.

I got type error when I import routes from `~pages`

Below is my code in my router:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import routes from "~pages"; // got error here

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

and error:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `/// <reference types="vite-plugin-pages/client" />` in **env.d.ts**

It's mentioned in [README](https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages#overview).